# Where to enable structure navigation bar in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I noticed that for some file types as html, yaml, xml there is kind of a structure navigation bar showed at the top of the PyCharm editor window. I want to enable this bar for python code, so that I can see the path in the code structure to where my cursor currently is. You can see an example of that bar on this image: [image: structure navigation bar]

Does anyone know how this bar is called and how I can enable it for python files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that feature is called "Show breadcrumbs" and can be enabled in the Settings->Editor->General->Appearance. It works for python files only starting from 2017.1 version.